# UIDatePicker in UITableViewCell update UITableViewCell textlabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have been going through the processes of setting up a UIDatePicker in a UItableViewCell that is revealed when selected a UITableViewCell above it then collapses when you select any other UITableViewCell in the UITableView.

I have created this code by going over loads of documentation from other people as well as apples less than average [UIDateCell example](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html).

So far I have done this

- show & hide cell
- add UIDatePicker to cell

The one thing I am not sure how to do is once the date has chaned how do I pass that date back to the UITableViewCell UILabel above the UIDatePicker cell?

I am capturing the date in a selector method.

This is what the code looks like.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//.. set up view, UITableView (because its a subview to this view) delegate and data source etc then create UIDatePicker

//Get datepicker ready
    datePickerForCell = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePickerForCell.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePickerForCell addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//...
}

#pragma mark UITableViewStuff
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [sheetsTableView beginUpdates];
    // typically you need know which item the user has selected.
    // this method allows you to keep track of the selection
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            if (editingStartTime == true) {
                editingStartTime = false;
                [sheetsTableView endUpdates];
            } else {
                editingStartTime = true;
                [sheetsTableView endUpdates];
            }
        }
    }
}

//.. sections method
//.. rows method etc

//.. change height of cell that has picker in it to hide and show when needed
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) { // this is my picker cell
        if (editingStartTime) {
            return 219;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if ((indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0) || (indexPath.section == 3 && indexPath.row == 0)){
        return 180;
    } else {
        return self.sheetsTableView.rowHeight;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            // Date
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Date";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"1/2/17";
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            // UIPicker
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:datePickerForCell];

        }

//.. other cells below this


#pragma mark - datepicker
- (void)datePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker*) datePicker
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];


    NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    NSLog(@"%@", test);

}
```

So my question is, how do I pass test string (even though I have not formatted it correctly yet) to the the UITableViewCell UITextLabel in indexPath (0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an ivar that will serve to store the content that you want to give your label. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath you have an if, where, if the indexpath is the cell you assign this content to label

In datePickerChanged you must complete the content of ivar and give a reloadData in tableview.

Comment: omg... what a complete IDIOT!!!! i just realised how easy this is... I was thinking i would have to access some sort of UIDatePicker delegate... oh man I feel stupid (this is was 2 months holiday dose to your head)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            // Date
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Date";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:datePickerForCell.date 
                                                  dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle 
                                                  timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            // UIPicker
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:datePickerForCell];

        }

//.. other cells below this
```